# How can I keep one cat from eating from the other cats bowl?

Tags: cats, health, diet, eating

I’m in university and i keep a cat where i live out of town while i’m in school and move back home for the summer. My cat cannot regulate her eating and she needs special food but the other cats do not need these special restrictions. How can i help my cat to eat her own food at certain times and not eat the food of the other cats? We cannot get a feeder that reads microchips. We have tried mixing her food in with the other cats food so she gets her food while eating the other food but this is not working as she is still overeating.

Comment: FYI https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/28562/two-cats-eating-each-others-differently-prescribed-food https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/9600/cat-ditches-own-bowl-and-goes-to-other-cats